# Capture ID of user running a report through ReportViewer Control

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportviewer

We're currently using the ReportViewer control in an ASPX page to render reports to users in remote processing mode.

Users do not have access to the report server, but we'd like to identify who has run reports, so we'd like to pass in the application user id either as a parameter or otherwise so we have this visibility.

AS the application is running the reports, the application's username is inserted into the ExecutionLog table. Is there a way of either overriding this to allow for custom input or some way of passing in a parameter when running the report to be able to capture this. The ExecutionLog has an XML field for additional information that looks promising, but I'd settle for some way of inserting the user id into the parameter string.

I can't seem to find a way of doing this without, approaches I've considered:

- Adding a UserId input parameter to each report - I really don't
  want to do this, a huge amount of reports will need amending and we'd still need to parse out the username from the query string.
- Impersonating as the user, we can't do this,there is no direct access to the server and users will not all have windows credentials
- Capturing the info separately in the application database; this may be workable, but we'd like some way of linking this back to the executionlog of reporting services

I'm sure that we can't be the only people with this issue, but so far google has failed to turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge, as I see it, is how to get the application's User ID into the report-generation process, given that the actual report generation takes place on a different server and the only way you have to communicate with it is through the `ReportViewer`'s methods, events, and properties.  (Or the Report Execution web service, but you said you were using the ReportViewer control.)

I really think that adding a parameter for the user id and setting it programmatically (perhaps when the ReportViewer's `SubmittingParameterValues` event fires) would be your best bet.  The Execution Log has a column called Parameters that is supposed to contain parameter values.

I agree that manually adding and configuring a new parameter on more than a half dozen or so reports would be tedious and error prone.  However, since report definitions are XML files and can be both fetched from and written to the report server programmatically (using the Report Management webservice), you could fairly easily automate that process.

It would be quite possible to determine the XML fragment you need to represent your new User ID parameter, and then write code to fetch each report definition, insert the new fragment in the appropriate place, and write a new copy of the report definition to the server, ready to be tested.

The only other option I can think of would be to try something with a custom [Security Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155029.aspx), but I'm not familiar enough with that to know whether you could bridge the application-report server gap with that.

Comment: Thanks Ann, that's useful information. We've ended up going with my 3rd option, capturing the information in the application database. We're using the `GetExecutionId()` method of ServerReport to return the Execution ID and save it along with the userID